# how append a option to dropdown in ajax jquery?

Tags: jquery

append not working after ajax call pls help me, when i am calling ajax, ajax get method working perfect but value to adding to dropdown

```
<script>
  function getcity(){
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',


            url: 'http://localhost:8000/apiv1/mobileap/getcity/',
            success: function (data) {

                var my_obj = data;

                       $.each(my_obj, function (i, z) {
              var id = my_obj[i].pin;
              var tagn = my_obj[i].name;
                                                      $('#selcity').append('<option>hello</option>');

            });

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });

     };


</script>
```

Comment: Upload full HTML here please

Comment: pls see https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-ihdvTOzUwHGx0t5Z78PQprkE1eWrC8o/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What did you see in console when you receive back result of ajax request?

Comment: all thing working fine, append working outside ajax, but in ajax not working, data is coming from api perfectly